# Parseval's Theorem and Resistance/Current

Tags: sequences-and-series

When current I flows through resistance $R$, energy dissipated per second is the ave. vale of $RI^2$. Let a periodic ( but not sinusoidal) current be expanded in a Fourier series $I(t) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(c_n\,e^{120\pi i\  n t} )$. Give a physical meaning to Parseval's theorem for this problem.

My approach so far was to square the absolute value of the series. I also considered converting the exponential aspect of the function into its corresponding $ sin + cos$ form. However, I am not really sure how to articulate the physical aspect of this function in words.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I might have Parseval's theorem wrong here; I'm a bit rusty so I'm not sure if there should be some other constant on the right side of the first equation.

In this case, (I think that) Parseval's theorem explicitly states that
$$
60\ Hz\int_{0}^{1/60} |I(t)|^2\,dt = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |c_n|^2
$$
Noting that $P = |I|^2R$, we can rewrite this as
$$
60\ Hz \int_{0}^{1/60} P(t)\,dt = R\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |c_n|^2
$$
That is, the average energy dissipated per period (which seems to be $1/60$ seconds in this case) is given by $R\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |c_n|^2$

Comment: I'm not sure if an integral has to be involved. My book says that on the right it should just say the average value of the energy dissipated over a period. In addition, does the exponential part of the function not play a part at all? It too has an n in its exponent, and I sense that the question is asking me to phrase the answer in a form that says the total heat is equal to the sum of the heats associated with each nth harmonic.

Comment: In other words, what I have come up with is this: The heat energy dissipated corresponding to the nth harmonic is proportional to the average of (cn)^2(cos(120nπt) + isin(120nπt)^2. So, the total heat energy is equal to the sum of the heats dissipated for each nth harmonic.

Comment: See the latest edit, maybe it makes a bit more sense now.  I'm not sure how exactly your textbook phrased Parseval's theorem.  It seems though that your notion of "adding the heat from each harmonic" is on the right track.  Note in my question that the last integral I have is a formula for the average power per period, i.e. the "energy dissipated per second".